# Java Array List: Como mostrar rm uma Jlist os valores e as Posiçoões do Array de String

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Fiz este código na classe:

```
public class Dados {
ArrayList<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList();

public void cadastraContato(Contato contato){
    contatos.add(contato);
}
public String  numeroDeContatos(){
        return contatos.size()+ "";
}
public String listarContatos(){
    int n = contatos.size();
    int r;
    String text = null;
    for(int i =0; i<=n; i++){
         r = Integer.parseInt(contatos.get(i).toString());
        text = contatos.get(i).toString();
    }
    return text;
}
```

}

Código no Jframe do evento do botão add:

```
    private void btCadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String nome = tfNome.getText();
    String email = tfEmail.getText();
    String cpf = tfCpf.getText();

    Contato c = new Contato(nome, email, cpf);

    dados.cadastraContato(c);
    lbTotal.setText(dados.numeroDeContatos()+ " Contatos cadastrados");
    tfNome.setText("");
    tfEmail.setText("");
    tfCpf.setText("");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Contato cadastrado com sucesso!");
    System.out.println(c);

    int index = Integer.valueOf(dados.numeroDeContatos()) -1;
    lstContato.setModel(model);
    model.addElement(index + dados.listarContatos());
}
```

O que está de errado? e o que posso fazer pra achar a solução?

Comment: Qjual o problema que ocorre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i =0; i<=n; i++){
         r = Integer.parseInt(contatos.get(i).toString());
        text = contatos.get(i).toString();
    }
```

-seu "text =" ele vai sobre escrevendo toda vez que passar so substituir por "+="
mas recomendo que vc use uma StringBuilder ;)
espero ter ajudado